# Repository Pattern whith complementary objects (agregates)

Tags: domain-driven-design, services, repository-pattern

Refactoring an old API into a new one, because of several tools using it (admin and some mainteinance scripts) and compatibility with older versions reasons the database structure must remain the same.

I have a table **user** and another table **user_optionals** related 1:1. The **user_optionals** are just a bunch of fields with some extra options set by the **user**.

This, in my app, is currently reflected by a **User** and a **UserOptional** models.

Thus I'm using the repository pattern, each one has it's own repo, **UserRepository** and **UserOptionalRepository**.

I'm a bit concerned of having to inject and handle two different repositories in my services since a **UserOptional** won't exist if its related **User** previously doesn't.

I've been reading, and seems to fit in a Domain Driven Development concept known as an Agregate, but still not sure how to deal whith it.

So I'm wondering if I should apply any pattern or methodology here which agrupates both. Maybe grouping both on a unique Model or creating a new repository composed by a **UserRepository** and a **UserOptionalRepository**, maybe I'm overthinking it...

Comment: Isn't this case is just about that your `User` aggregate should contain the `UserOptionals` as an entity or as an invariant? If so rethink/redesign your model as so, then your repository just need to take care of correctly hydrating your `User` object filled the proper invariants.

Comment: Dont have two repositories for the same database

Comment: I'm not clear on the problem, having to inject two repos to a service doesn't sound awful, and its solved by just making it one repo. Adding UserOpional as a property of User to make an aggregate object, also solves the issue, but makes your User object bigger. would that be an issue?

Comment: Exactly why do you have a user optional table rather than put it all in user?  Do you not have known good default values for these optionals?

Comment: Well, legacy code. I'm trying to refactor all the project in a new framework

Comment: @Ewan I'll likely go with the agregation you suggested

Comment: @vivoconunxino saying "legacy code" is the same as saying "I don't know". Forget the past. With the needs you have today, why do you need both?

Comment: @candied_orange I'm allowed to change the framework, coding it as I want, but not the database, in fact, both projects, the old and the refactores new one will coexist for sometime sharing the same database

Comment: BTW, users already have a lot of fields, and still makes sense having some user options separated into another table

Comment: @vivoconunxino make sure to edit that requirement into the question. It's a bombshell. Given that you have to keep the old project working why are you making the new one? What need is it satisfying?

Comment: @candied_orange right, edited and added a bit of context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is normal (but not not mandatory) that aggregates span multiple tables in your database.

If UserOptional entities are subordinate to User entities -- if they don't get re-assigned from one user to another, if the life cycle of a UserOptional is within the life cycle of a User, if there is an invariant that spans multiple UserOptional within the same User... then it can make sense to have a "aggregate" that encloses both the User entity and also the related UserOptional entities.

The User entity in your domain model would probably act as the "aggregate root".

One heuristic to consider -- do you need to support concurrent modification of UserOptionals that are related to the same User?

Aggregates are, in effect, a [coarse grained lock](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/coarseGrainedLock.html) that ensures that modifications to data within the boundary of the aggregate happens one at a time.  If that constraint is going to introduce too much contention for your use cases, then you may need to treat UserOptional as a distinct aggregate that it represents.

Comment: The user is who modifies its own options, so I guess concurrency it's not a problem.